# What is primal infeasible solution in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I am using GAMS for solving a MILP problem which includes binary variables. However there is a problem in the solution. Surprisingly, I have seen that one of the binary variables in the solution has a found value of "-1" another one "2". That is not acceptable. I do not know what happened. GAMS gives me the message `primal infeasible`.

Comment: Can you show me the code?

Comment: here is the link https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_primal_infeasible_solution_in_GAMS?_tpcectx=profile_questions

Comment: GAMS gives me this code:"resolved with fixed discrete variables".something is wrong in GAMS because it is not logical case.

Comment: First, if GAMS reports the problem as infeasible, you should not rely on the variable levels. Better check the solver & model status first and look at the variables only, if these status codes do not indicate a problem.
Then: What version of GAMS did you actually use? I just tried your model with the recent version (24.8.2) and that solved it without any problems, and also with all binary variables either 0 or 1.

Comment: so,Lutz do u mean my model does not have problem,right?,actually I solved it without any problem before,however since yesterday I faced this problem,is it probability to overload gams has difficultis?

Comment: Right, running it with a recent version I do not see any problem with your model. Therefore I was wondering if you are using the same GAMS version I used, or if you used an old one. If the latter is the case, you might be OK after switching to the new one.